# Wordpress home page shows a 404 error

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress site in one domain (say **domain1**)

Now i created a wordpress in another domain (say **domain2**)

and put the theme from **domain1**.

And updated the DB with the Db from **domain1**

Now while i take new wordpress site's(ie wordpress in domain2) home page ,it shows a 404 error

Will any one please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just put the wordpress tables from one domain into the DB of another domain. There are some configuration values saved on the DB that need to be updated with the name of the new domain.

That could be the source of the 404 error. To solve this, open the SQL or CVS DB file in a text editor and search/replace the old domain name for the new one.

Comment: I really don't get how it would result 404. The homepage shows at least an error-message or a white-page or something, but not 404! If it is a custom 404, it comes from wordpress, than its there. If its a regular 404, the domain, the directory reached, but the default directory-index is missing. How else could he get 404?

Comment: Well, I can think of more than one possibility, here is one: You type www.domain.com/index.php?p=2, wordpress process the request with its configuration values and tries to load www.olddomain.com/index.php?p=2.

Comment: Ajweb, i have done, what you said.Now my home page is loading fine.But the links are not working .While i check the Permalink Settings in admin side, it was custom setting and there is some values.Now i edited it to default.Still the links are not working.Any idea?

Comment: Have you copied your .htaccess to the new domain? The .htaccess itself should work fine from one domain to another, but some FTP applications don't show/download invisible files by default, so perhaps the .htaccess was not copied to the new domain. In any case, you should be fine by adding the .htaccess file again with the settings from your permalinks page. Permalinks setup instructions: http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Where.27s_my_.htaccess_file.3F

Comment: thanks Ajweb and sorry for late reply.Do you know any word press plugin that can used for external dB login ,apart from word press plugin 'External DB authentication' becuase it is not compactable for word press latest version 3.0.4

Answer (score 1):

You have to follow certain steps to 1) move WordPress within a host, and 2) move Wordpress to a different domain.

This mostly involves changing URLs in the database either by moving Wordpress in a certain way so that the database gets updated, or updating the database after the fact. And updating permalinks in .htaccess, too.

See [Moving WordPress « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) and [How to Move WordPress Blog to New Domain or Location  »  My Digital Life](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/10/01/how-to-move-wordpress-blog-to-new-domain-or-location/).

None of these steps will change URLs hardcoded in theme files, like header.php or the style sheet if you edited those while building a theme.

SQL queries to change URLs in the database via phpmyadmin.

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://olddomain.com','http://newdomain.com');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com');
```

Comment: Firstly thank you for your informations. I have done, what you said.Now my home page is loading fine.But the links are not working .While i check the Permalink Settings in admin side, it was custom setting and there is some values "/%postname%/".How can my links get work?

Answer (score 0):

If the files are there, under the domain. First, try domain2.com/index.php. If it works, you must add an .htaccess file to your directory with the enrty

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

If it is not there, the domain points to different directory. Then it is not a wordpress related issue, only server config which can be resolved by your host company.

Answer (score -1):

Trouble is, a 404 error can come from so many places.  Did you just register the new domain?  If so, it might just take a while for the DNS changes to propogate.

You will probably also have to change the configuration settings for the new domain's wordpress site.  You can find detailed instructions on how to change it (wp-config.php) here http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php

Comment: You don't get 404 on DNS error, you reached the server if you have 404.

Comment: Yes, 404 is file not found, but I've seen some hosts throw up a 404 while the system is still setting up.

Comment: So by default, it points to an empty directory? If its a new domain, you don't get any response until the DNS change propagated. When it is, you get the actual IP of the server and the server delivers you the content from the directory.